# Can volatile be used everywhere const is used?

Tags: c++, constants, volatile

I wonder if `volatile` can be used anywhere `const` can, and what each case would mean.

```
volatile dummy_class
volatile dummy_class&
dummy_class volatile*
dummy_class *volatile
dummy_class volatile *volatile
```

These are all distinct cases when `const` is involved, do the same semantics apply for `volatile`?

Comment: I believe the answer is Yes.But to post it as an answer One would need to provide evidence for each of the above,from the Standard and those are distributed across various sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is section 3.9.3 *CV-qualifiers* from C++11 draft n3290:

> A type mentioned in 3.9.1 and 3.9.2 is a cv-unqualified type. ***Each type* which is a cv-unqualified complete
>   or incomplete object type or is void (3.9) has three corresponding cv-qualified versions of its type**: a
>   const-qualified version, a volatile-qualified version, and a const-volatile-qualified version. The term object
>   type (1.8) includes the cv-qualifiers specified when the object is created. The presence of a const specifier
>   in a decl-specifier-seq declares an object of const-qualified object type; such object is called a const object.
>   The presence of a volatile specifier in a decl-specifier-seq declares an object of volatile-qualified object type;
>   such object is called a volatile object. The presence of both cv-qualifiers in a decl-specifier-seq declares an
>   object of const-volatile-qualified object type; such object is called a const volatile object. The cv-qualified or
>   cv-unqualified versions of a type are distinct types; however, they shall have the same representation and
>   alignment requirements (3.9).51

So `const` and `volatile` can be used in the same spots, possibly in conjuction.

Paragraph 3 of that section notes a slight difference in how they apply to class objects:

> Each non-static, *non-mutable*, non-reference data member of a const-qualified class object is const-quali-
>   fied, each non-static, non-reference data member of a volatile-qualified class object is volatile-qualified and
>   similarly for members of a const-volatile class. See 8.3.5 and 9.3.2 regarding function types that have
>   cv-qualifiers.

but that's pretty logical.

`volatile`-qualified objects have stricter requirements for the *as-if* rule, namely:

> Access to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.

The volatility gets attached to the object in the same way `const` does:

```
dummy_class volatile* // non-volatile pointer to volatile object
dummy_class *volatile // volatile pointer to non-volatile object
dummy_class volatile *volatile // volatile pointer to volatile object
```

For non-static member functions (§9.3.1):

> A non-static member function may be declared const, volatile, or const volatile. **These cv-qualifiers
>   affect the type of the this pointer** (9.3.2). They also affect the function type (8.3.5) of the member function;
>   a member function declared const is a const member function, a member function declared volatile is
>   a volatile member function and a member function declared const volatile is a const volatile member
>   function.

So volatility like const-ness applies to the type of `this` inside the function.

Neither `const` nor `volatile` can be applied to static member functions.

Answer (score 6):

Almost. Both are *cv-qualifiers* and can be used almost everywhere where the other can. The only place they appears in C++ grammar is here:

> cv-qualifier:
>       `const`
>       `volatile`

And the rest of the grammar references them as *cv-qualifier*.

Note that one place you didn't mention where *cv-qualifiers* can be used is:

```
struct X {
    void f() const;
    void g() volatile;
    void h() const volatile;
};
```

See http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184403766 for a use of the later.

**However,** there is a rule that you *cannot combine `const` and `mutable`* like in:

```
stuct X {
    mutable const int x; // error
    mutable volatile int y; // valid
};
```

The relevant place int the standard is [dcl.stc]:

> The mutable specifier can be applied only to names of class data members (9.2) and cannot be applied to names declared const or static [...]

Comment: Don't bother providing `volatile` overloads everywhere though. Volatile is most useful only for primitive types, and rarely enough not to be bothered by its existence.

Answer (score 1):

Any variable can be declared `const` or `volatile` (or both), but they have different semantics.

The `const` keyword indicates that a variable is constant. The `volatile` keyword indicates that a variable may have its content changed even when you don't assign anything to it.

For example, if you have this piece of code

```
int a = ...;
int b = ...;
int sum1 = (a + b) * 2;
int sum2 = (a + b) + 16;
```

and enable optimizations on your compiler, the compiler can optimize the previous code into this:

```
int a = ...;
int b = ...;
int temp = a + b;
int sum1 = temp * 2;
int sum2 = temp + 16;
```

This optimization occurs because the compiler assumes that the values of a and b will not change when calculating sum1 and sum2, therefore a + b will not change. If you declare a or b as `volatile`, this assumption is negated, which means that the compiler will produce code that calculates a + b each time and not store it in a temporary location. This is because by declaring a or b `volatile` indicates that a or b (and, consequently, a + b) may have changed between the execution of the two statements.

Although `volatile` seems like a useless keyword, it has its uses in multithreading applications and when doing memory-mapped I/O (that is using the system memory for communicating with hardware). For instance, in the GameBoy Advance, one has to read a specific memory location to determine which keys are pressed at a time. If you declare a pointer to that specific memory location as volatile, it will always be guaranteed that you will read that specific data from memory each time.

Comment: Depending on the context, `const` is closer to "read-only" than to "constant".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth the presence of `const_cast` makes "readonly" a fragile concept when const is involved. I'd use constexpr for read-only stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In C++2003 I think you cannot define a `static int volatile` member of a class while you can do this with a `static int const` member: the latter becomes a constant expression and as long as you don't need an address or a reference of the object you'll be fine. For C++2011 I don't know whether this has changed because you can initialize members in the class definition and I don't know if this extends to static members.